# DBCP Datasource pooling?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am implementing Apache DBCP connection to improve efficiency of my program that executes multiple queries.

The issue is that just having a connections pool is not enough because I have multiple data sources as well (I have m - datasaources and each data source has n- connections).

How can solve this issue?

Do I need connection pools for every data source? Is there a pool for datasources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a pool for each datasource.

Comment: Meaning I need a sort of synchronized hashmap for PoolingDataSource objects?

Comment: Why? Just create all the pools during startup and store them in an immutable `Map` (using `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` or [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `ImmutableMap` for example. Since it can't be modified, it doesn't need to be synchronized.

Comment: Because I create datasources dynamically therefore can not create them at startup

Comment: Again, why? You can create a pool initially containing 0 connection, dynamically creating connections as needed; creating datasources dynamically is a bit weird. Do you mean you don't know at startup which datasources can be used? Are they created after some user input? In that case (if you must), use a `ConcurrentHashMap` (with `putIfAbsent()`), or [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `LoadingCache` which will manage all the concurrency problems for you.